# I'm at a loss trying to get a background image for a <div></div>, it just wont show

Tags: html, css

So i'm not sure what is going on here but when I try to add a background image to this:

```
 <div id="navigation">
            <span id="message"> </span>
 </div>
```

it wont show up it just does nothing. When I try to add a background color it works just fine! here is the .CSS code.

```
#navigation{
    width: 78.5%;
    height: 23.5%;
    background-image:url("images/Chatwindow.png");  
}
```

I have tried other images and those don't work either. The image works in other places but this div will just not allow a background-image. What am I missing here?

I've also tried:

```
background-image:url('images/Chatwindow.png');
```

Comment: Remember that the path should be relative **to your CSS file** not the path you're currently visiting in your browser.

Comment: Are you sure that the image path is correct? Have you tried setting the width and heigt to pixels?

Comment: Is your CSS file located in a folder?

Comment: Yes my CSS file works just fine, it's just the background-image that doesn't do it's job. The rest of the file is working. I tried changing it to px but it did nothing to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please sure the image file's relative path, relative to css file.
try "/images/Chatwindow.png" or "../images/chatwindow.png".

actually you can open the chrome developer tool(press F12), change to Network tab and refresh page, after that you can see the "Status" of the image file, if shown 404 the relative path is  incorrect

Comment: It shows nothing, I know the path is correct though. I used the path for other background and it worked just fine.

Comment: I need to do "../images/chatWindow.png" I'm an idiot and forgot my .css file is in another folder. One of those days!

Answer (score 1):

I tried you css in fiddle `and it didn't worked`.

the i added :

```
html,body{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

and voila!! :D => **http://jsfiddle.net/w4tsC/3/**

and keep the css path relative as commented...if you have a doubt, set inline css to check!! :)